# If $b $ divides $ad $ with$ \mathrm {gcd}(a,b)=1$, then $b $ divides $d $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a\in \mathbb {Z} $ and $a,b \in \mathbb {N} $. Suppose that $b $ divides $ad $ where  $\mathrm {gcd} (a,b)=1$. What can you conclude from the above assumptions?

I have a feeling that we must have $b $ divides $d $, but I am unsure and have no intuition guiding me as to a formal way to express what I believe is the conclusion.

Comment: Yes, with these assumptions can conclude $b|d.$ A simple proof may be based on using $ax+by=1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Using Bezout's theorem, there exists $(u,v)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $au+bv=1$. Try multiplying by $d$.